# What are the values of the confint() function in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning

What are these 2.5% and 97.5%? I didn't understand what is written in the documentation. Anyone could explain to me in a more practical terms?

[image]

Comment: The help page, under "Value," states "A matrix (or vector) with columns giving lower and upper confidence limits for each parameter. These will be labelled as (1-level)/2 and 1 - (1-level)/2 in % (by default 2.5% and 97.5%)."  Which aspect(s) of this need explaining?

Comment: @whuber these labels. I've heard about a confidence interval having 95% of confidence,in this case, [11.79, 14.27] of 95% chance to my variable value be there. I don't know how to interpret these two numbers: 2.5% and 97.5%

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=two-sided+confidence.

Comment: @whuber Maybe I should study more statistics, where can I go to study deeper into confidence intervals? Which branch of statistics? I will search for a book about this

Comment: The relevant concepts are covered in all introductory stats textbooks, so you will do well to consult your favorite before you look any further afield.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A 95% confidence interval (CI) is in fact an algorithm with the following property:

Suppose you re-run an experiment many, many times (from sampling from the population over measuring your data to fitting your model) and estimate the same parameter of interest with an associated 95% CI. Then, because of noise in your data, you will get a different parameter estimate and a different 95% CI each time. *But 95% of these different CIs will cover the true parameter value.*

(Yes, this is unintuitive, and frequently gotten wrong. [Here is a recent discussion.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/472455/1352))

Now, of course a 95% CI is not unique. It consists of two end points. You could in each case calculate a lower 1% limit (such that when you repeat the experiment many times, the true parameter value will be lower than this 1% limit in only 1% of cases) and an upper 96% limit (i.e., out of your many experiments, the true parameter value will be higher than this limit in 4% of cases). The two together will yield an interval that covers the true parameter value in 95% of cases, so this is a 95% CI.

However, symmetry is appealing. So the "standard" 95% CI consists of a lower 2.5% limit and an upper 97.5% limit. When you repeat your experiment many times, the true parameter value will be below the CI in 2.5% of cases and above it in another 2.5% of cases - and the CI will cover it in 95% of cases.

The numbers you see are the lower (2.5%) and upper (97.5%) limits of this standard symmetric CI for your three estimated parameters in the single run of the experiment you are analyzing right now.

[The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) is somewhat confusing, but there is a lot of material there.

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much. So if I understood well, these numbers refer to how percentage of the data is _bellow_ of these limits. So, we have 2.5% of the value bellow 11.79 and 97.5% of the value _bellow_ 14.27. Is that correct?

Comment: These two comments appear to be at cross purposes: it is not the case that the confidence values refer to "percentage of the data."  They refer to the *sampling distribution of the parameter estimate.*  The two concepts are vastly different.

Comment: @whuber: you are right, I misread the OP's comment, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @user45523: no, the CIs have very little to do with how the *data* are distributed. They pertain to the distribution of the *parameter estimate*. (For instance: collect more and more data from the same distribution and estimate the mean. Its CI will get narrower and narrower and therefore contain less and less of your observed data.)